# Need to change LIMIT into something else

Tags: sql, postgresql, limit

Is there a way to change "LIMIT 1" and get the same output? I have to get client's name, surname and a quantity of books that has the most books

```
SELECT stud.skaitytojas.name, stud.skaitytojas.surname,
       COUNT (stud.skaitytojas.nr) AS quantity
FROM stud.egzempliorius , stud.skaitytojas
WHERE stud.egzempliorius.client = stud.skaitytojas.nr
GROUP BY stud.skaitytojas.nr
ORDER BY quantity DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Please explain why you can't use `limit`.

Comment: Your statement will not compile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the row with the highest quantity using `row_number()`

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * , row_number() over (order by quantity desc) rn FROM (
        SELECT stud.skaitytojas.name, stud.skaitytojas.surname, COUNT (stud.skaitytojas.nr) AS quantity
        FROM stud.egzempliorius , stud.skaitytojas
        WHERE stud.egzempliorius.client = stud.skaitytojas.nr
        GROUP BY stud.skaitytojas.name, stud.skaitytojas.surname
    ) t
) t where rn = 1
```

If you want to include ties for the highest quantity, then use `rank()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres supports the ANSI standard `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY`, so you can do:

```
SELECT s.name, s.surname, COUNT(s.nr) AS quantity
FROM stud.egzempliorius e JOIN
     stud.skaitytojas s
     ON e.client = s.nr
GROUP BY s.name, s.surname
ORDER BY quantity DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Also notice the use of table aliases and proper `JOIN` syntax.  I also prefer to list the columns in the `SELECT` in the `GROUP BY`, although that is optional if `s.nr` is unique.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the answer was unaccepted?